# Make code analyzers ignore AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

We have added `#pragma warning disable` to the top of all our `AssemblyInfo.cs` files. The built-in code analysis in Visual Studio 2015 professional, though, continues to analyze that file. What can we add to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#pragma` applies to compiler warnings, since Code analysis (binary) is applied to the produced assemblies, and the pragma information was lost during the compile stage, binary code analysis cannot be aware of this suppression.

The #pragma will work for the true Roslyn roles which act ont the sources instead of the binaries. If you do not enable "Binary Code Analysis" your warnings should be suppressed just fine. Do make sure you have an alternative enable for the rules you're disabling.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is the implication that there is no way to make code analyzers ignore AssemblyInfo.cs?

Comment: I suggest adding this to the answer: "Make sure you don't have Binary Code Analysis checked as part of your ruleset."